# PHP Declaring variable in class that is made from another variable

Tags: php, oop, variables

I yesterday discovered strange issue in my class - hope you know some answers. Consider such a class:

```
class Person {

public $height = 90;
public $weight = $this->height * 0.8;

}
```

This class returns an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" and it seems i can not declare variable in class that is variable itself. Can I only set "static" values to variables in class (i mean static like directly declared like string or int no static like "static $var = 'xyz'";Why is that happening?

Thanks,
Kalreg.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, you can use only constant expressions when defining default [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) values in PHP. That means *you can not use* anything that will be evaluated at run-time. Since `$this` refers to dynamic instance value, it is run-time, obviously, and cannot be used in such definitions.

Answer (score 0):

properties cannot have dynamic values in the class definition, but you can define the weight in the __construct method if you want:

```
class Person {

  public $height = 90;
  public $weight;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->weight = $this->height * 0.8;
  }

}
```